# Challenge : replace reflection

Tags: java, reflection, javafx

After writing several [javafx.scene.control.TableView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html) and seen the code has tedious, I have made this utility static function:

```
public class TableViewHelper {
   public static <T,F> void addColumn(
      TableView<T>     table,
      TableColumn<T,F> column,
      final String     fieldName,
      boolean          sortable,
      double           width      )
   {
      column.setCellValueFactory(
         new Callback< CellDataFeatures<T,F>, ObservableValue< F >>(){
            @Override public ObservableValue< F > call( CellDataFeatures<T,F> p ){
               T t = p.getValue();
               ObservableValue< F > value = null;
/*HERE IT IS*/ Class<T> tc = (Class<T>)t.getClass();
/*HERE IT IS*/ try { value = (ObservableValue<F>)(tc.getDeclaredField( fieldName ).get( t )); }
/*HERE IT IS*/ catch( Throwable x ){ x.printStackTrace(); }
               return value;
            }});
      column.setSortable( sortable );
      column.setPrefWidth( width );
      table.getColumns().add( column );
   }
}
```

Table Row class:

```
public class ChatMessage {
   public ChatMessage( String sender, String message ) {
      _date   .set( new Date());
      _sender .set( sender );
      _message.set( message );
   }

   final SimpleObjectProperty< Date > _date    = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
   final SimpleStringProperty         _sender  = new SimpleStringProperty();
   final SimpleStringProperty         _message = new SimpleStringProperty();
}
```

usage:

```
public class ChatView
   extends
      BorderPane
{
   ChatView() {
      TableViewHelper.addColumn(
         _view, new TableColumn<ChatMessage,Date  >( "Date"    ), "_date"   ,  100.0 );
      TableViewHelper.addColumn(
         _view, new TableColumn<ChatMessage,String>( "Sender"  ), "_sender" ,  100.0 );
      TableViewHelper.addColumn(
         _view, new TableColumn<ChatMessage,String>( "Message" ), "_message", 1200.0 );
      setCenter( _view );
   }
}
```

Using reflection (flagged by "HERE IT IS" comments) to get value of the fields by their Java field names works **but I wish to do otherwise, without adding code in the "usage" section.**

**Can you propose other ways (with code), without using reflection?**

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can't access a field by string except through reflection. The only alternative would be generating Java code dynamically.

Comment: Yes, generating code is a solution. No other idea?

Comment: If it's an option, you can redesign to keep these values in a Map.

Comment: JavaFX offers its own containers, delegate to a wrapper is more complex and add codes into "usage" section

Answer (score 0):

You can create an interface

```
public interface Property<T, X>  {
    public X get(T object);
    public void set(T object, X value);
}
```

The interface `Property` can be used in places where you currently use reflection:

```
public static <T,F> void addColumn(
        TableView<T> table,
        TableColumn<T, F> column,
        final Property<T, ObservableValue<F>> property,
        boolean sortable,
        double width)
{
   column.setCellValueFactory(
      new Callback< CellDataFeatures<T,F>, ObservableValue< F >>(){
         @Override public ObservableValue< F > call( CellDataFeatures<T,F> p ){
            T t = p.getValue();
            return property.get(t);
         }
      });
   column.setSortable( sortable );
   column.setPrefWidth( width );
   table.getColumns().add( column );
}
```

Well, either this, or I am missing something which says this cannot be done with JavaFX.

Comment: The goal is to simplify the usage of JavaFX. Can you write the "usage" part, please?